# alert box from asp.net 3.5 Code-Behind

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, alert

```
protected void ddlLanguage_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    if (ddlLanguage.SelectedValue=="es-ES")
    {
        Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;

        page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "Script", "<script language='javascript'>alert('All content may not be in Spanish. Do you want to continue...');</script>");            
    }
}
```

All I want to do is display a simple alert box but all in vain...nothing pops-up. need some ayudar.

Comment: Are you sure that the page is actually doing a postback? Do you have AutoPostBack set to true on ddlLanguage?

Comment: Several problems in your code, but the most prominent is that you are asking for confirmation using `alert`. For this, you need to use `confirm`

Comment: ddlLanguage.Attributes.Add("OnSelectedIndexChanged", "return confirm(All content may not be in Spanish. Do you want to continue?');");

Comment: @lcarus same result.. (nothing)  :(

Answer (score 2):

You need to verify if the startup script is not registered already. Check out [this post.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy.aspx)

Also you can build your custom MessageBox in ASP.NET. Check out [this one](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSASPNETMessageBox-3e8c6273).

Answer (score 2):

You can also achieve in this way

```
protected void ddlLanguage_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
  if (ddlLanguage.SelectedValue=="es-ES")
   {         
      Response.Write("<script>alert('All content may not be in Spanish. Do you want to continue...');</script>");            
   }
}
```

Comment: that seems like a easy fix, it works. But are there any good practice s for doing this..

Comment: currently when the alert box is displayed the background goes black. is it possible to keep my website in background and just display this alert box on top of it..

Comment: I am trying to use a confirm box instead of alert but its not working even if I cancel it still changes the content to spanish

Answer (score 0):

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "showalert","Alert Message", true);

This works for me without Postback
try this